# svn export only some directories

Tags: svn, version-control

How can I export from Subversion and ignore specific directories?

The repo contains the following structure.

```
/project1
    /doc
    /daily
    /history
    /sql
    /test_cases
```

To export the project to a production directory, I need to not include the test_cases and doc directories. The production directory should appear as:

```
/project1
    /daily
    /history
    /sql
```

The doc and test_cases are valuable and should be version controlled with the project. However, they should not be delivered to a production directory. Perhaps the doc would not do much damage, but if something is run from the test_cases directory, it could easily do damage to the production system.

I could rmdir the unwanted directories after the export, but there is no post-export hook. Is the best that can be done to use a script to do the export to production?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `--depth` to control, which parts should be exported. In your case, it might look like this:

```
svn export --depth=files https://svn.example.org/project1 project1
svn export --depth=infinity https://svn.example.org/project1/daily project1/daily
svn export --depth=infinity https://svn.example.org/project1/history project1/history
svn export --depth=infinity https://svn.example.org/project1/sql project1/sql
```

Comment: I agree that this would work, nosid. It sounds like I must write and maintain a script for each project. Projects make new directories at will. They would not get exported until the script is updated or if -everything- is exported. We could depend on omitting any directory named "doc" or "test_cases", but that seems awkward.